# store custom class to TimestampedKeyValueStore

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have incoming messages from Kafka stream, incoming messages from topic contains a headers. I'm trying to process, store them into Kafka's TimestampedKeyValueStore and then forvard those messages further. ATP they are processed correctly, but they are stored without the headers, probably bcs of default serde. I have created new class based on kafka's ValueAndTimestamp, but I have also included headers as byte[]. My questions are, is it possible to store a such custom class and if yes, what does it require?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - A custom class is stored by a Serde.

Yes - the Store interface can be replaced with your own implementation.

https://kafka.apache.org/36/documentation/streams/developer-guide/processor-api.html#implementing-custom-state-stores

Comment: I really want to avoid creating a custom StateStore, I would like to know how to store a custom class to KeyValueStore. I couldn't find any example that I could move on from.

Comment: As answered, a Serde does this for you, and the `Materialized.with` method is what you would use while you build your stream/table. https://kafka.apache.org/36/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/Materialized.html#with(org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde,org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde)